# How to change name of "More" tab on tabbedPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I working on Xamarin.Forms and i need to change name of "More" tab on tabbed page. How  I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

> I working on Xamarin.Forms and i need to change name of "More" tab on tabbed page. How I can do that ?

You can use custom render to change TabbedPage "More" Tab in Android project, take a look the following code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace gensture.Droid
{
public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage tabbedPage;
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    public MyTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
     
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            tabbedPage = e.NewElement as TabbedPage;
            bottomNavigationView = (GetChildAt(0) as Android.Widget.RelativeLayout).GetChildAt(1) as BottomNavigationView;              
            ChangeFont();
        }

    }
    void ChangeFont()
    {
        
        var bottomNavMenuView = bottomNavigationView.GetChildAt(0) as BottomNavigationMenuView;

        for (int i = 0; i < bottomNavMenuView.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var item = bottomNavMenuView.GetChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView;
            var itemTitle = item.GetChildAt(1);

            var smallTextView = ((TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(0));
            var largeTextView = ((TextView)((BaselineLayout)itemTitle).GetChildAt(1));
            if(smallTextView.Text=="More" && largeTextView.Text=="More")
            {
                smallTextView.Text = "test";
                largeTextView.Text = "test";
            }
           
        }
    }
}
 }
```

The screenshot:

[image]

**Update:**

You need to make TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom", to make "More Tab" appear.

```
<TabbedPage
x:Class="gensture.TabbedPage1"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#999999"
android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="Black"
android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom">
<!--  Pages can be added as references or inline  -->
<ContentPage Title="Tab 1" />
<ContentPage Title="Tab 2" />
<ContentPage Title="Tab 3" />
<ContentPage Title="Tab 4" />
<ContentPage Title="Tab 5" />
<ContentPage Title="Tab 6" />
```

Comment: Its not woking for me

Comment: @Divinegdk Please show some code here, and take a look my Tabbedpage in my update reply.